# How to use @Html.ActionLink to generate an empty fragment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How can I generate a link with ASP.NET MVC @Html.ActionLink to have an empty fragment.

```
<a href="#">Title</a>
```

I know that `@Html.ActionLink("Title", "action", "controller", null, null, "fragment", null, null)` will give me `<a href="/controller/action">Title</a>` or `<a href="/">Title</a>`, but knowing the right way to do this would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by `empty fragment`?  It's called `ActionLink`, so, the intention of that helper method is to link to a specific action.  What do you want your expected output to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ActionLink` helper is more often used to generate url properly based on the action, controller, route values etc and anchor tag based on htmlattributes etc. Here in your case you can just write `<a href="#">Title</a>` in your cshtml, no need to use action link.
But if you really want to use it try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Title","",null,new {href="#"})
```

here non-specification of action will generate root `/` as the `href`, so override it by specifying the html attribute overload of the helper.

Comment: A very good response to a question that others might have dismissed as not worth the effort. Well done!